# What do I need for my blog posts to open on Facebook app the way Kotaku does?

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-graph-api, blogs

So I have seen this before in a few sites but Kotaku is the only one that I know out of the top of my head that does this. 
When their site is in mobile size it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vX7aZ.png).
But when accessed from facebook it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qXSz.jpg).
While normal sites shared on facebook open like **i.stack.imgur.com/JMIDc.jpg**  (sorry dont have enough rep to post 3 links) How can I get my site to open like Kotakus? I am already using facebook Open Graph properties to change the way my site displays shared content but that doesnt affect the way it opens up. Thanks in advance!

Comment: They are using Instant Article https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instant-articles

Comment: ohhhhh thats it! awesome thanks